# Is there a countable dense subset?

Tags: manifolds

If a manifold $M$ is $\sigma$-compact,
does $M$ possess any **countable dense subset**?

Comment: It means 'If $M$ is $\sigma$-compact then $M$ has a countable dense subset'?

Comment: Manifolds are usually required to be second-countable by definition, and any second-countable space is separable (i.e., has a countable dense subset). Does your definition of "manifold" require second-countability?

Comment: @tetori Yes, I wanted to describe as that is.

Comment: @ZevChonoles Thank you, so much!! I understand it is a property of just manifold.

Answer (score 0):

But if you wanted to use $\sigma$-compactness, and not manifold-ness, you could do that too.

Every compact set has a countable dense subset, namely the union of finite $(1/n)$-nets.

And for a countable union of compact sets, you take the union of those countable dense subsets.

Comment: The ordinal $\:$[$\omega_1$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_uncountable_ordinal)$+1\:$ with the [order topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_topology) is compact but does not have a countable dense subset. $\hspace{.84 in}$